# How Can I remove Functionality of max Invalid Password Attempts

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

How Can I remove Functionality of max Invalid Password Attempts from Asp.Net Membership.?

```
<membership>
            <providers>
                <clear/>
                <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
             connectionStringName="con"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
             enablePasswordReset="true" 
             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
             requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
             minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
             minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
             passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
             applicationName="/"/>
            </providers>
        </membership>
```

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796472/disabling-account-lockout-with-the-sqlmembershipprovider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This thread might help you:

[Disabling account lockout with the SqlMembershipProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796472/disabling-account-lockout-with-the-sqlmembershipprovider)

Basically you could just set number of attempts to Int32.MaxValue. It's not exactly what you wanted but it will work for most cases.